# dpkg erroring when running commands

Tags: apt, dpkg, 20.10

When I run commands which use things like `apt`, I get this error a lot.

This error specifically was form me trying to fix the ussue:

`dpkg --configure -a`

```
dpkg: error processing package libavcodec58:i386 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.32-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.3-2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libavcodec58:i386
```

How do I fix this issue, and what could have caused it?

Comment: I posted the comment as an answer so you can accept it and mark the question as resolved that way.

Comment: `sudo apt install --reinstall libavcodec58:i386`  please add the output to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `libavcodec58` is in an inconsistent state, I think it failed initial installation and ended up half-installed.

Reinstall that package and it should clear up the errors:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libavcodec58
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command.

Step 1:

> $ sudo apt-get update --fix-missing

Step 2:

> $ sudo apt-get install -f

if this don't help try this:

Step 1:

> $ sudo apt-get update

Step 2:

> $ sudo apt --fix-broken install